# Focusing Issue in Clarion 6

Tags: clarion

We have an application in Clarion 6 which does not have any mdi windows in it anywhere.  These have all been removed and made non-mdi.  When this one window is open and other windows are opened off of it (say from a button click), the first window will 'pop out' in front of the other windows when the items are refreshed based on a timer.

How can this be stopped?  We do not want this window to get the focus and cover other windows automatically this way.  However, the display data does need to refresh every so often.